# Compare two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, replace, compare

I know that this question has been asked several times and I did read them all.   However, my situation is little different I can still can't get the right results with my SQL statement below.

I have two tables as shown below:

```
TABLE A
######################################################################
   |   ID   | IP_Address    | Username  | Comments
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
    1       128.        abc     travel to US
    2       127.        dzd     author
    3       127.        abc     It's not redundant at all. Not offering a single function
    4       124.        deb     I just lost laptop.  How do I report it?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



TABLE B
######################################################################
   |   keywords     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
    author
    How do I report
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My intention is to pull out all records in TABLE A when the Comments column partially matches one of the keywords in TABLE B.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT ID, IP_Address, UserName, Comments FROM TABLEA
FULL JOIN TABLEB
ON TABLEA.Comments LIKE TABLEB.Keywords
WHERE TABLEA.Comments IS NOT NULL AND TABLEB.Keywords IS NOT NULL
```

It works but it only pulls out the EXACT match, not a part of the comments.
In my sample, it pulls out "author" record but not "I just lost laptop.  How do I report it?" record.

Is there a way to twist my query to meet my requirements?

Thanks

JPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add % to the LIKE clause

```
SELECT ID, IP_Address, UserName, Comments FROM TABLEA
FULL JOIN TABLEB
ON TABLEA.Comments LIKE '%' + TABLEB.Keywords + '%'
WHERE TABLEA.Comments IS NOT NULL AND TABLEB.Keywords IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: As simple as it is but I could not think of! Sometimes, just a break would fix all problems!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need.

```
SELECT ID, IP_Address, UserName
FROM TABLE1 T1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Keywords FROM Table2) T2
WHERE CHARINDEX(T2.Keywords,T1.Comments) >0
```

The CROSS APPLY could be replaced with the full join, but cross apply works better if there are more columns in the 2nd table.

Comment: Thanks LeeG.  Your results completely match with RADAR's suggestion.   

Thanks much.